# Microsoft Excange antispam forges

Tags: anti-virus, smtp, spam-prevention, exchange-2010

Could someone please tell me about How MS Exchange fights against spam.

I have experienced Mdaemon server setup. It could use DNS records checks (existance of ptr record, accordination of peer ip address with HELO address dns record, etc.), it could make a delay of data transmitting (spamers MUST send billions of letters, they could not wait for half of a minute to server respond). So point is to minimize letters, which then checked in antispam software.

Which soft (or components) I could use for this?

Maybe I completely wrong in question point, so which is better way to gain less spam without headache.

Answer (score 1):

The very first feature I would turn on is the IP Blacklist provider (in your organization config under Edge (or in some cases Hub) transport settings in the console. You can set it up for a few different providers like spamhaus.org, etc.